# Нужна помощь в настройке wsgi файла pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

При развертке сайта на pythonanywhere появился ряд ошибок, на фото код wsgi и ошибки какие появляються [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Виртуальное окружение не настроено вероятно, поэтому не может Django импортнуть. 
Сначала нужно поставить окружение и Django - той версии, что используешь. Там есть терминал через него ставишь

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.6 mysite-virtualenv
(mysite-virtualenv)$ pip install Django==2.1.4
```

Затем во вкладке Web указываешь путь к окружению, что создал и там же перезагружаешь приложение.

Comment: это уже пофиксил но появилась новая проблема можеш помочь?  https://ibb.co/gdVnJMZ